# categorical (co)product of pairs of spaces and pointed spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology

What's the (co)product of $\mathsf{Top}^*$ and $\mathsf{Top}^2$?

What about wedge product and smash product?

Someone says the smash product is not a categorical product,why?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The coproduct in pointed space is the wedge sum. I suggest this as an exercise, but it's surely also been discussed on this site before. For the second question, it should be easy to figure out in general that if $\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D}$ are categories with products, $\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{D}$ is a category with products and what its products look like.

Comment: @Thorgott While OP denotes it $\operatorname{Top}^2$, it isn't actually a product category.